# Remove warning: "variable 'result' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false" in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I have seen questions similar to this one but none of them helped me due to the fact that I could not find one that was using a template.
For a homework assignment, I have to code a stack that can be used with any type of variable, so I have decided to use a template. This prevents me from initializing variables, my code gives me a warning for the function pop() can anyone give me suggestions on how to remove such warning?

my function pop():

```
template<typename T>
    T stack<T>::pop(){
        T result;
        if(!empty()){
            result = tos->data;
            Node<T> *tmp = tos;
            tos = tos->next;
            delete tmp;
        }else{
            std::cerr<<"ERROR empty stack"<<std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Do not remove warnings. _Fix the bug instead_

Comment: Initialise `result` to a value before using it.   Without the initialisation, depending on the type `T`,  the definition `T result` can leave `T` uninitialised - for example, if `T` is `int`.   If `!empty()` is not true, then the `else` is reached, leaving `result` uninitialised.   The `return result` then will have undefined behaviour (since it accesses the value of an uninitialised variable).

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to initialize T due to not having a type I can predict, I have to use both a string class we implemented and int for future parts of this project. I can't think of a way to initialize it so it would work for both of them. To my knowledge, my string class will be initialized to my default constructor's specifications, while int will be unitialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of simply printing to `std::cerr` your `pop()` method should throw an exception if it hits something it cannot deal with. Silently failing and returning an uninitialized object *will* cause problems later.

You can throw an exception like this:

```cpp
//...
else {
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR empty stack");
}
//...
```

You then only need to declare `result` within the `true` branch of your if statement.

Comment: It's worth noting that [`std::dequeue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) opted to have separate `get_back` and `pop_back` methods because `pop` can be a little tricky to handle in the empty case in a useful way.  Nowdays would probably either throw an exception or return a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: This works! Thanks! My professor also finally replied to my email I sent last week and I can apparently just use an assert(!empty()) before I pop an element out of the stack. I will use this one though since it seems neater.